# Unable to execute *catkin* commands using *RUN* in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, ros, catkin

I want to use a customized ros-indigo on docker. I prepared the following Dockerfile

```
FROM ros:indigo-robot

RUN echo "source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
RUN mkdir -p /home/catkin_ws/src
WORKDIR /home/catkin_ws/src
RUN catkin_init_workspace
WORKDIR /home/catkin_ws
RUN catkin_make
RUN echo "source /home/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
```

However, it throws me an error at both *RUN catkin_init_workspace* and *RUN catkin_make* that says

```
/bin/sh: catkin_make: command not found
The command '/bin/sh -c catkin_init_workspace' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Surprisingly, it builds succesfully if I change *RUN* with *CMD* for *catkin* commands, i.e. the following Dockerfile builds just fine

```
RUN echo "source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
RUN mkdir -p /home/catkin_ws/src
WORKDIR /home/catkin_ws/src
CMD catkin_init_workspace
WORKDIR /home/catkin_ws
CMD catkin_make
RUN echo "source /home/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
```

What is more surprising is these catkin commands work perfectly on a container that is built separately on top of any *ros-indigo* image.

This clearly indicates that either *RUN* is not an appropriate way to invoke *catkin* commands or I am invoking it incorrectly.

Now, given that the nature of *CMD* command is different from the *RUN* command, it does not make sense to use it in my case. Hence, I shall appreciate if someone can point me out the right way to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to setup a proper bash environment for the commands to work (by default Docker uses sh to execute commands). These commands worked for me:

```
FROM ros:indigo-robot

RUN echo "source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
RUN mkdir -p /home/catkin_ws/src
WORKDIR /home/catkin_ws/src
#RUN /opt/ros/indigo/bin/catkin_init_workspace
RUN /bin/bash -c '. /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash; catkin_init_workspace /home/catkin_ws/src'

WORKDIR /home/catkin_ws
RUN /bin/bash -c '. /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash; cd /home/catkin_ws; catkin_make'
RUN echo "source /home/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 4):

Your second case will build because `CMD` is not executed during the build.  It simply defines the default command to execute when starting the container.  See the docker [CMD docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) for more information.

The root of your problem is that `~/.bashrc` is not being called in the shell used by the `RUN` instruction.  As a result, the environment variables are not present to allow `catkin_make` or other ros commands to work.  I address this issue in my images by running a command similar to the below.

```
RUN . /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.sh && \
    catkin_make
```

You will need to activate the environment in each `RUN` instruction that needs those environment variables because the shell is not re-used between `RUN` commands.

*Edited to include the improvement from David Maze.*

Comment: If you use the [standard `.` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_18) instead of bash's `source` extension command, it will work in all Bourne-compatible shells, including the minimal shell in Busybox and Alpine base images, and you won't need to set `SHELL`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: This is great, it worked like magic. Thank you so much. For future readers, this is what the working Dockerfile looks like exactly  
`FROM ros:indigo-robot`
`RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential`
 `RUN mkdir -p /home/catkin_ws/src`
  `RUN . /opt/ros/indigo/setup.sh && catkin_init_workspace         /home/catkin_ws/src`
    `RUN . /opt/ros/indigo/setup.sh && cd /home/catkin_ws && catkin_make`
    `RUN echo "source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc`